# Print pos tag with removed adjectives (NLTK)

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

```
abc = nltk.pos_tag(info)
      print(s for s in abc if s[1] != 'ADV')
```

Returns: generator object pos. locals>. genexpr> at 0x000000000E000D00>

If using [] round print I get "Invalid syntax"

Comment: You are using Python 3 aren't you? The list comprehension *needs* square brackets, the `print` function *must* have round brackets. You cannot pick and choose what to use where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're simply trying to get an output of parts of speech that are not "adverbs"?

Using parentheses results in passing the print function a [generator comprehension](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_list_comprehension.php). Try something like this if you just want the output all at once (generator in list comprehension):

```python
print([s for s in abc if s[1] != 'ADV'])
```

Note: You can also achieve the same output without using print().

Also, fyi: [Last I checked](https://pythonprogramming.net/natural-language-toolkit-nltk-part-speech-tagging/) "ADV" doesn't correspond to a pos tag. If you're looking to eliminate adverbs, then I think the correct pos tag adverb types are "RB", "RBR", and "RBS".

Updated the answer, based on Alexis's response below. He is correct, the explanation wasn't complete. Pasting his feedback from comments:

> There's generators, and there's list comprehensions. print(s for s
>   ...) passes print a generator; the version with square brackets uses
>   the generator in a list comprehension, to make a list.

(please also upvote alexis's comment)

Comment: Yes, the tagset for the default `nltk.pos_tag` uses the `RB*` tags.

Comment: Right solution, but the explanation is confused. There's generators, and there's list comprehensions. `print(s for s ...)` passes `print` a generator; the version with square brackets uses the generator in a list comprehension, to make a list.

Comment: Thanks @alexis ! I've firmed up the answer based on your observation.

Answer (score 0):

For adjectives, try this:

```
abc = nltk.pos_tag(info)
print [s for s in abc if s[1] != 'JJ']
```

Comment: @SafenessAndSafe: do you know which one?

Comment: @usr2564301 :"Invalid syntax"

Comment: @SafenessAndSafe: yup. You may not be aware but you are using Python 3, not 2. It's a tell-tale error.

Comment: @usr2564301 : Yes, so what should I do for it to work? Thanks

Comment: @SafenessAndSafe: always check what [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) has to say about this.

Comment: @usr2564301 : I have stared at it for ages, using () will not work and [] won't, is it because it needs to be str? If so how, please

Answer (score -1):

From https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1783#issuecomment-317174189

> The `pos_tag()` function is trained on Sections 00-18 of the Wall Street Journal sections of OntoNotes 5.

From http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#module-nltk.tag

> It uses the Penn TreeBank tagset https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html

To catch all adverbs, check for `RB*` tags.

Using list comprehension, check the first 2 characters of the tag and check for the `RB`, e.g.

```
>>> from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
>>> sent = "I am running quickly"
>>> [word for word, pos in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)) if pos.startswith('RB')]
['quickly']
```

To catch adjectives, check for the `JJ*` tags:

```
>>> sent = "I am running quickly"
>>> sent = "The big red cat is redder than apple"
>>> [word for word, pos in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)) if pos.startswith('JJ')]
['big', 'red', 'redder']
```

If you only check for `JJ` with `JJ*` (i.e. `.startswith('JJ')`), you'll miss the comparative and superlative adjectives:

```
>>> sent = "The big red cat is redder than apple, it's the best in the world"
>>> [word for word, pos in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)) if pos.startswith('JJ')]
['big', 'red', 'redder', 'best']
>>> [word for word, pos in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)) if pos == 'JJ' ]
['big', 'red']
```

To remove simply use `not`:

```
>>> [word for word, pos in pos_tag(word_tokenize(sent)) if not pos.startswith('JJ')]
['The', 'cat', 'is', 'than', 'apple', ',', 'it', "'s", 'the', 'in', 'the', 'world']
```